# How to replace tkinter label dynamically (updated data is within for loop)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a function that will only start after a tkinter button have been pressed. Within the function there is a for loop that iteration through a dataset that I have like to display through tkinter label dynamically. Meaning to say there will only be 1 tkinter label and its value will constantly be changing between iterations in the for loop.

The closest I have gotten was at every iteration a new label will be created and it keep on expanding downstairs which is not what I am looking for. Anyone can advise me on any possible direction I can take?

Below is the framework of codes that I have tried.

```
root = tk.Tk()

order_json = tk.StringVar()

def update_label(order):
     order_json.set(order)
     root.update()

def order_func():
     for i in range(len(dataset)):
          data_to_display = dataset[i]

          label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=order_json)
          label.pack()
          update_label(order)
```

so instead of a single label that is constantly updated, every iteration creates a new label under the old one and it just keeps on expanding.

[image]

I would appreciate if anyone can guide me along. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can't use `for` or `while` loops for the real time updating in tkinter GUI, this is because tkinter is already in a `mainloop` due to which using a `for` loop or `while` makes the GUI stop responding till the loop ends but if the `for` loop or `while` loop is small and does end then we can use them like if we want 10 labels in a frame we can just use

```
for i in range(10):
   Label(root, text='Label %s' %i).pack()
```

But if you need to see a change time to time dynamically, In your case updating the label to see the dataset. For these purposes we use `after(ms, callback, args)`. Also don't use `sleep` instead use `after(ms)` without any callback given.

Lets say I want to see a counting. In which I just want the label to update every 0.5 secs I can use something like this.

**Example**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

Label = tk.Label(root, text=1, font=('', 20))
Label.pack()

def update(count=1):
    Label['text'] = count
    # 500ms , calling the same function again and again.
    root.after(500, update, count+1)

update()
root.mainloop()
```

---

### Now, Answer to your problem

As I don't know what `dataset` is I just take a *list of 1 to 50* .

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

order_json = tk.StringVar()

dataset = [i for i in range(50)]
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=order_json, font=('', 20))
label.pack()

count = 1
def order_func():
    global dataset, count
    if count>=len(dataset): return     # This will exit the function when done
    order_json.set(dataset[count])     # This will update the label 
    count += 1
    root.after(100, order_func)        # This will recall the callback function

tk.Button(root, text='Play', command=order_func).pack()

tk.mainloop()
```